# Is this an example of an unprovably true statement in set theory? (A Corollary to the axiom schema of separation)

Tags: logic, set-theory, first-order-logic, model-theory, meta-math

In ZFC, the axiom of separation is given as follows.

Let $\phi(x, w_1,\ldots, w_n)$ be a wff formula in FOL, for free variables $w_1,\ldots,w_n$. Then,
$$\forall w_1,\ldots,w_n\forall A \exists B\forall x(x\in B \iff (x\in A \wedge \phi(x,w_1,\ldots,w_n, A)))$$

It is trivially easy to prove within a formal system for any instantations of $A$ and $B$, $B\subseteq A$. Likewise, a proof outside of the formal system that this holds for any property $\phi$ is about as straightforward as well.

My question is this: Is this statement provable within ZFC, or would this be an example of an unprovable but true statement? At first glance, it looks to me that it would be unprovable, since a proof would seem to require you to quantify over $\phi$, which is not permitted in first order logic. If this is provable, what would a proof of this look like?

Comment: If you consider $\phi$ to be a variable, tis is not even a statement in ZFC. If you substitute $\phi$ with some specific formula, then you get a statement. And the statement you get will be provable in ZFC (and in fact will be an axiom).

Comment: @mihaild That should be an answer.

Comment: True? True in which model?

Answer (score 3):

If you consider $\phi$ to be a variable, this is not even a statement in ZFC, because ZFC, as first-order theory, not only can't prove statements with quantifiers over predicates, but can't even formulate them.

If you substitute $\phi$ with some specific formula, then you get a statement. And the statement you get will be provable in ZFC. In fact it will be an axiom - one of axioms you get from schema of separation.

Comment: +1. To elaborate for the OP, a ZFC-undecidable statement needs to be *in the language of ZFC in the first place* to be properly referred to as such ("today is Tuesday" is ZFC-undecidable, technically sorta kinda, but ...).

Comment: @NoahSchweber I think I understand what you're saying that makes sense. You can't refer to predicates in a first order logic, so there is no statement like $\forall\phi$. The fact that this is true for any $\phi$ is a statement of the metalanguage, is that correct? Let me know if I am still off.

Comment: Yes, when we say "for any $\phi$", it's not part of theory. This is why separation isn't an axiom of ZFC, but rather schema.